# Running JMeter for 62,000 users

Tags: jmeter, stress-testing

Our client asked us to run a stress test on their Web application simulating 62,000 users (threads), the test consists of 13-15 HTTP requests, with 1 second delay between every HTTP request, the test should run for 10.5 hours continuously.
I had previous experience with JMeter running up to 10,000 users, but have not tried for larger number.
Is there a limit for the number of threads that JMeter can handle, or is this limited by the hardware of test server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle it is limited by several factors including the configuration (CPU/Mem) of your JMeter machine. That said, it is a VERY large number of threads for just one JMeter. To be honest: I wouldn't run even 10000 threads on one machine. You might want to look into using JMeter distributed, see the manual (http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf).

Comment: Thank you, i ended up reducing the number of threads, and added a loop controller, for me the results were as i expected,

Comment: Your solution is wrong, reducing number of threads and changing loop size is a different Load Profile

Answer (score 5):

agreed with Ray when you run jmeter for this much amount of thread the distributed testing is the best option, and the hardware and network shall be capable to handle this kind of load, and in case you want to do that in short go for http://blazemeter.com, they are Scalable from 1,000 to 100,000 concurrent users.

Answer (score 2):

Except running script remotely, you'll need to configure your script with minimal usage of CPU and memory. 
Use [JMeter best practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and [JMeter tuning tips](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips) to reach it